Fastify + Websocket - Connected and Disconnected
fastify.register(require('@fastify/cors'))
fastify.register(require('@fastify/websocket'));
fastify.register(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.get('/example', { websocket: true }, (connection, request) => {
  connection.socket.on('connection', (message) => {
    console.log('Connected!');
  });
  connection.socket.on('message', (message) => {
    console.log('Received message:', message);
    connection.socket.send(\`Hey there! Received your message ${message}\`);
  });
});
})
fastify.listen(
  { port: process.env.PORT || 3000, host: "127.0.0.1" },
  function (err, address) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(`Your app is listening on ${address}`);
  }
);

This is the simplest code block for the ease of understanding. When I access ws://127.0.0.1:3000/example , I have back to back Connected and Disconnected messages with Error Code 1006

What am I missing ?  I have also tried writing the fastify.get(.. standalone instead of inside fastify.register(...
Thanks in advance for any help!
